# Marker Draggable sem LongClick

Tags: c#, android, xamarin, maps

Ao setar um `Marker` como `Draggable(true)`, é preciso segurar clickado sobre o mesmo para ele virar "Draggable".

Eu preciso que simplesmente ao arrastar o dedo sobre ele, ele arraste. 
Um exemplo seria o **99taxi**, que tem o `Marker` solto.

Comment: Dá uma olhada na resposta do pessoal do CommonsWare aqui: https://stackoverflow.com/a/3897611/7762411. Eles implementam as coisas no onTouchEvent

Comment: Rapaz, obrigado pela indicação. Acho que é isso que preciso mesmo.